# How to Join Tables in BigQuery Using a Custom Dimension as a Unique Identifier

Tags: sql, join, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm wanting to join my Google Analytics table with another table within Google BigQuery, but I'm wanting to use a custom dimension as my unique identifier. Below is the query I have so far, but it doesn't like my syntax for using custom dimension #3 as the unique identifier. This is the error message I get:

> **Cannot access field index on a value with type ARRAY> at [6:26]**

Any ideas how I can make this work?

```
SELECT
*
FROM
  `wehco-bi.64884663.ga_sessions_20180928` AS GA, UNNEST(hits) AS hits
  <br/>LEFT JOIN `wehco-bi.BlueConic.ao` AS BC
  <br/>ON GA.customDimensions.index.3 = BC.bc_profile_id
<br/>LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Why do you have <br /> tags in your query??

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend joining the whole ga_sessions table. Select only column you need (more efficient and cheaper) before you can use customdimensions you need to get them out of their arrays. Thea easiest way to do this is to create subquery.

```
with base as (
SELECT
DATE,
(SELECT value FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions) WHERE index=1 LIMIT 1) AS hit_level_cd1,
(SELECT value FROM UNNEST(t.customDimensions) WHERE index=3 LIMIT 1) session_level_cd3
FROM `wehco-bi.64884663.ga_sessions_20180928` AS t, UNNEST(hits) AS hits
)
SELECT DATE, hit_level_cd1,session_level_cd3
FROM base AS GA
LEFT JOIN
`wehco-bi.BlueConic.ao` AS BC
ON GA.session_level_cd2 = BC.bc_profile_id
LIMIT 100
```

first I create temporary base table where I unnest custom dimensions (I did both for session and hit level show you the difference), then I use one of them to join them to the new table same as you tried to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want work with array I would suggest start here https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#accessing-array-elements

What you are trying to do must be done using a different sintax like this

```
GA.customDimensions[OFFSET(2)]
```

It will access your third element in the array.